# How to plot validation images using ImageDataGenerator?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to build a model for image classification but can't figure out how to plot validation images with class predicted (and probability) like in this guide:

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/hub_with_keras#check_the_predictions

As i use ImageDataGenerator i can get information about predicted classes and probability but i can't get images itself.

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(10,9))
for n in range(30):
  plt.subplot(6,5,n+1)
  plt.imshow(image_batch[n])
  plt.title(labels_batch[n])
  plt.axis('off')
_ = plt.suptitle("Model predictions")
```

I get ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (400,80,80,3) into shape (400)

I know that the problem is in -> image_batch[n]

Please advise me how to pass information about image to imshow().

P.S. 
code for image generator i use:

```py
img_generator = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255)

image_batch = img_generator.flow_from_directory(
    path,
    target_size=(size, size),
    color_mode='rgb',
    class_mode='categorical',
    batch_size=batch_size
)
```